# problema nombre usuario al hacer login

Tags: php, mysqli, php7

al momento de hacer login necesito que me aparezca el nombre del usuario , no el
usuario.

usuario:agus

nombre: agustina

la consulta la tengo de esta manera

```
 <?php

  session_start();

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

  $usuario = $_POST ['usuario'];
  $contraseña = $_POST ['password'];

  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdprint");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM trabajador WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND 
  clave = '".$contraseña."'";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

  $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

  if ($filas>0) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;
  header("location: home.php");

  }else {
   exit("<h1>Usuario no existe </h1><a href='login.php'>Volver</a>");
  }

   }

    ?>
```

también la realice así y tampoco me funciono

```
$query = "SELECT nombre = $nombre FROM trabajador WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND clave = '".$contraseña."'";
```

al momento de loguear cree en un archivo php aparte

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/estilos.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Bienvenido: <?php echo $_SESSION ['username'] ?></h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

aquí es donde debería aparecer ejemplo BIENVENIDO(A) AGUSTINA

he realizado varias consultas y nada , nose que podría estar haciendo mal

saludos , gracias por su tiempo.

### --
--   Estructura de tabla para la tabla `trabajador`

```
 CREATE TABLE `trabajador` (
`cod_emp` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`usuario` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`clave` varchar(30) NOT NULL




INSERT INTO `trabajador` (`cod_emp`, `nombre`, `usuario`, `clave`) VALUES
(0, '', '', ''),
(0, '', '', ''),
(1, 'Agustina', 'agus', '123456');
```

Comment: Podrías indicar la estructura de tu tabla y qué mensaje obtienes al ejecutar tu código?

Comment: La tabla trabajador tiene los siguientes campos:
cod_emp (int),usuario (varchar(20)),clave (varchar(30)),nombre (varchar(50)),no es que me salga un error, sino que cuando hago el login me sale usuario como login , estoy tratando que me salga el nombre del usuario creado, ejemplo el nombre  se llama  Agustina ese deberia salir , pero me sale usuario : agus , sty viendo como poder hacer que cuando haga loguin me salga el nombre , para dejarlo asi" BIENVENIDO (A) agustina"

Comment: Puedes añadir los datos de prueba de tu tabla y su estructura en tu pregunta

Comment: listo, gracias.

Comment: El nombre del usuario lo tienes en almacenado en la tabla. Deberias recuperalo en este If :

  if ($filas>0) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;
  header("location: home.php");

Aqui no veo que tomes ningún valor de la tabla
No deberia ser algo como:

  $_SESSION['username'] = $filas['nombre'] ??

Comment: claro deberia ser asi para recuperar el nombre del usuario y aparesca en la pantalla de bienvenido(a), pero al ponerlo asi no me aparese nada ya que no lo tengo en la consulta de sql, es ahi donde estoy chocando $query = "SELECT * FROM trabajador WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND 
  clave = '".$contraseña."'"; aqui es donde estoy haciendo la consulta de usuario y contraseña, no se como podria agregar el nombre o se podra hacer otra consulta?,agradecería una ayuda, saludos

Comment: Pon atención a la respuesta de @BetaM, es el deber ser cuando haces un login. Tu código tiene muchas vulnerabilidades y debes aprender como hacer buena programación. Si quieres la respuesta rápida y corta ve a la respuesta de Samsepi, que no es mala y resuelve tu problema, pero vendrán cosas peores si no mejoras tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código debe quedar así:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdprint");
$query = "SELECT * FROM trabajador WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."' AND 
clave = '".$contraseña."'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas > 0) {
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $datos['nombre'];
    header("location: home.php");
}
```

Lo que estás haciendo aquí:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $usuario;
```

Es decirle a la `$_SESSION['username']` que tome el valor de el `$_POST['usuario']`:

```
$usuario = $_POST ['usuario'];
```

Espero te sirva, si tienes dudas espero tus comentarios

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta , si me sirvió era lo que necesitaba, pero como @Alberto Siurob dice tengo mucho que mejorar el código, trato cada día ir aprendiendo , es mi 1 año estudiando , ahora no están pasando php pero un pincelada , la información que nos entregan es muy poca , por este sitio que encontré he aprendido mxo mas y se agradece cada apoyo de ustedes , volviendo al tema de la respuesta del código se agradece por el tiempo dado, me falta a un mucho que aprender

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios respecto al código actual:

- Considera empezar a implementar consultas preparadas<sup>1</sup> (*no es una buena idea permitir que la data que el usuario envía llegue directo a la consulta*)
- Agregar un `LIMIT 1` al final de tu consulta
- Hacemos uso del método `bind_result`<sup>2</sup>
- También empleamos al método `fetch()`<sup>3</sup>
- En este caso en lugar de un conteo de filas obtenemos el nombre del usuario mismo que obtendremos después al leerlo desde una variable que quedará vinculada a este.

  - Donde verificaremos en un condicional si el valor retornado es distinto de `NULL`, en ese caso si existe el usuario y manejamos el nombre obtenido
  - En caso contrario redirigimos de nuevo al login

**Importante**

- La propuesta de solución se basa enteramente en el código que expones, pero considera prestar atención a estos comentarios:

  - Las contraseñas no se guardan como texto plano si no mediante la generación de un *hash*<sup>4</sup> de ellas
  - Cuando una contraseña se almacena *hasheada* entonces se debe emplear algún método como `password_verify`<sup>5</sup> para evaluar que una contraseña sea coincidente con un hash dado

Dado lo anterior, entonces la lógica de la respuesta puede variar pero considero te servirá revisar todos los enlaces que te he facilitado.

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $usuario     = $_POST['usuario'];
        $contrasenia = $_POST['password'];

        $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","bdprint");

        $query = $conexion->prepare("   SELECT nombre 
                                        FROM trabajador 
                                        WHERE usuario = ? AND clave = ? 
                                        LIMIT 1
                                    ");
        $query->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $contrasenia);
        $query->execute();

        $query->bind_result($nombreUsuario);
        $query->fetch();
      

        if ($nombreUsuario === NULL) {
            header("Location: login.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $nombreUsuario;
            header('Location: home.php');
        }

    }
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- <sup>2</sup> [Método `bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)
- <sup>3</sup> [Método `fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch)
- <sup>4</sup> [Método `password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)
- <sup>5</sup> [Método `password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

*Aunque* por lo general si revisas incluso los enlaces el método `fetch` se emplea con la sintaxis de:

```
while ($algo->fetch()) {

}
```

Pero para este caso en específico no lo considere necesario dado que solo recuperas el nombre de un solo registro, pero no quiere decir que siempre sea así (*insisto checa de nuevo los enlaces*).

Comment: si estoy claro, tomare sus consejos y chequeare los enlaces, muchas gracias